# Onclick get the value of hidden dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the value of hidden dropdown value on change a specific dropdown and show it as an input radio button in the display. I have tried it in JSFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/3mf67pav/2/

```js
jQuery("#model").on("change", function() {
  alert(jQuery("#designation").val());
})

jQuery("#designation option").each(function(i, e) {
  (jQuery("<input type='radio' name='r' />")
    .attr("value", jQuery(this).val())
    .attr("checked", i == 0)
    .click(function() {
      jQuery("#designation").val(jQuery(this).val());
    }).add($("<label>" + this.textContent + "</label>")))
  .appendTo("#r");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="model" ide="model">
  <option>choose option</option>
  <option val="1.5inces">1.inches</option>
</select>

<select id="designation" title="Designation" name="designation" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Choose Option..</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>

</select>

<div id="r"></div>
```

Comment: It should be `id="model"`, not `ide="model"`.

Comment: It is not clear what you need. The code where you add radios, does not seem to match the description of the problem. Do you want different radios when you have a different option selected in the model?